# Where to locate png for nether portal in assets

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Where do I locate the png for nether portal blocks? I have already changed end portals to be entirely green but I cant locate nether portals. what file would it be in?

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you are using a texturepack** (not the default Minecraft textures, ex Conquest of the Sun texture pack), and on a version 1.9 or higher.

In the texturepack .zip file, go to

> assets/minecraft/textures/blocks

And you'll find a **portal.png** file. Edit it to change the texture.

This file usually consists in several images stacked vertically, to be able to add an animation effect to the portal.

---

**If you are using default Minecraft textures**, you can find the **textures_0.png** *(and following textures_1.png, 2, 3...)* file in the following folder :

> C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft

The portal texture is in around the middle, in the 17th column and 7th line.